# What's the difference "origin master" vs "origin/master"

Tags: git

What is the difference between a space and a slash when running git commands?

I sometimes see

`git push origin master` (which is a space)

and other times I see

`git rebase origin/master` (which uses a slash)

What is the difference in this convention?  Is it that the slash notation accesses a local cached copy whereas the space version actually reaches out to the remote repo (github) ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053597/why-do-i-need-the-master-in-git-merge-origin-master/22055959#22055959

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not a "convention". The former is two separate arguments in different positions with different meanings to `git push`, and the latter is a single argument which identifies the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.

Comment: Specifically, `git push origin master` is more generically `git push <remote name> <branch name>`.

Comment: @RyanStewart: Yes, exactly. And `origin/master` is shorthand for `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which is the full name for a remote-tracking branch. You can see these branches with `git branch -r`.

Comment: I understand that one is 2 separate arguments, and the other is 1 argument; I guess I don't really understand what the difference between specifying remote tracking branch vs specifying remote-name branch-name is.  To me, they both reference a remote repo and a branch in that repo, so why aren't they interchangable?

Comment: @sketchfemme: Because they *don't* both specify a remote repo and a branch in that repo. With `git push` you're specifying the remote repo, and you're specifying a refspec (which may be more than a bare branch name - read the manpage). With `origin/master` you're specifying a "remote" branch that's actually a local branch that tracks a remote and is updated with `git fetch` or `git pull`.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand.  Thank you.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Is it then possible to just write `git rebase master` instead of `git rebase origin/master`? Or are there really two different local master branches? One being a copy of the remote master branch and one being my own master branch? If so: When I `git pull` are both local master branches (one called origin/master and the other just called master) updated? I am very confused …

Comment: @erik: `master` is your local master branch. `origin/master` is your local "remote-tracking" branch, which represents the state of `master` on the `origin` remote, and is updated when you run `git fetch` or `git pull`.

Comment: @Kelvin: If it updates the `origin/master` branch in my local. Why I am able to see the recent pulled changes in my own `master` branch?

Comment: @DopedDude `git pull` updates the remote-tracking `origin/master` branch and then merges it into your local branch (which is presumably `master`). If you have no local changes the merge is a fast-forward. If you just want to update `origin/master` without modifying your local branch, use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`. `git fetch origin` should update all of your remote-tracking branches for the `origin` remote.

Comment: great.. got this part... I have some other queries and for those I have created a chat-room "http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84533/understanding-git". We can continue there.. Thanks.