# What is origin/master in git compared to origin master?

Tags: git

I wanted to add this question as a comment to the answer of @KevinBallard here [What's the difference "origin master" vs "origin/master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642273/whats-the-difference-origin-master-vs-origin-master), but my comment was to long.

So my question is:
If I am in a branch called `topic`, is it possible to just write `git rebase master` instead of `git rebase origin/master`? Or are there really two different local `master` branches? One being a copy of the remote master branch and one being my own master branch? If so: When I `git pull` are both local master branches (one called origin/master and the other just called master) updated? I am very confused …

---

Or maybe it is like this: `origin/master` is a local copy of the real remote master branch to which the remote was fetched (copied, i.e. just **overwritten**), and my local branch called `master` is only changed, when I `git merge origin/master` (or `git rebase …`). That is: When I `git pull origin master` both my local copy `origin/master` and `master` are updated/merged. Of course assuming that I am currently in the master branch (i.e. `git checkout master` was my last checkout).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- `master` is your local branch.
- `origin master` is the branch `master` on the remote repository named `origin`.
- `origin/master` is your local copy of `origin master`.

When you do `git pull` (what I consider as evil, anyone else?), it automatically does :

- git fetch : it copies `origin master` into `origin/master`. (and all other `origin xxx` into `origin/xxx`).
- git merge : it merges `origin/master` into `master`.

When you want to rebase master, you must do :

- git fetch
- git rebase origin/master

extract of `git help pull`:

> More precisely, **git pull** runs **git fetch** with the given parameters **and** calls **git merge** to merge the retrieved branch heads into the **current** branch

Comment: *and all other `origin xxx` into `origin/xxx`*: Ah, really? That is interesting. It fetches everything but only merges the master automatically. Thank you.

Comment: *`git merge`: it merges `origin/master` into `master`*, but **only** if I am currntly in the branch `master`, isn’t it?

Comment: @erik I added an extract of the man page which explains that without args, you call git fetch (which fetches all branches) then does the merge in the current branch.

Comment: @erik Personally, I never use `git pull`. I always use `git fetch` to fetch all the branches, then I rebase/merge with `git merge origin/xxx` or `git rebase origin/xxx`/

Comment: FWIW `git pull --rebase`

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Does `git pull --rebase` do a `git fetch` then `fit rebase origin/master`?

Comment: @roulette01 that's correct

Answer (score 6):

`<remote>/<branch>` named branch are managed automatically by git.

When you do `git pull`, what git really does is

```
git fetch  
git merge origin/master
```

`git fetch` automatically updates the `origin/master` local branch to point at the last commit of the `origin` remote's `master` branch.

So yes, when you call `git pull`, both are updated. That's because `fetch` updates `origin/master` and `merge` updates `master`.

> If I am in a branch called topic, is it possible to just write git rebase master instead of git rebase origin/master?

You can, but master is not necessarily the same as `origin/master` - though most of the time they are. So it is really up to you.

> Or are there really two different local master branches?

Yes they are two different local branches. They're just usually pointing to the same commits and share a common tree.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git pull` on any branch, actually, two operations are performed: `git fetch` and `git [merge|rebase]`.

The fetching just downloads all objects from remote repo, that is by default called `origin`. Among downloaded objects there are refs - they are pointers to some concrete commits. Some of those pointers are called *branches*. If there is `master` branch in a remote repo `origin`, then it will saved as `origin/master` inside your local repo - just to not interfere with your local branch with the same name.

After fetching, git looks at your config and, by default, tries to merge or rebase your current branch onto the branch from `origin` with the same name.

In config you can specify which local branch will be rebased upon which remote branch - so you can simply run `git pull` without additional params.

Comment: what do you mean by `the same name`? Do you mean, that if I am in a branch called `topic1` and I pulled just via `git pull` in effect it does `git pull origin topic1` (if origin is my default remote)? And `git pull origin topic2` pulls the branch `topic2` into my current branch (no matter how my current branch is called)?

Answer (score 1):

Branches are *just references to commit points*. Tags are also refs to commit points, but branches differ from *tags* because git, in certain situations, updates branch references automatically to point to another commit. These automatic updates happen, let say, when you create new commit point (`git commit`), then the branch that is  *current HEAD* gets updated to refer to the newly created commit point.

Git maintains two types of branches: local and remote. Local branch gets updated as described above. Remote branches are updated when you do: `git fetch`.

Also, you can have local branch to *track* remote branch, in this case `git pull` is just a convenience for the following two operations: `git fetch; git merge origin/<tracked branch>`.

Note that the local branch and the remote branch that tracks can have different names.

So, in your case, when you say `git merge master`, you are merging your *local master*. when you say `git merge origin/master`, you are merging the remote branch (that, eventually,  can point to the same commit as local master)

Also note that you *really merge commit point* that the branch point to (you can say `git merge <some commit>`), not branch itself.