# Why do I need the "master" in git merge origin/master?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

The convention when using git and you want to get changes from the server is:

`git fetch`

`git merge origin/master`

I know there is also `git pull`, but my specific question is about the syntax `origin/master`. What does the `master` part do? If I just do `git merge origin` (without the `master`) it seems to work. I know `master` is a branch, but if I'm tracking more than one branch of a remote, would the normal use case be to merge all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument(s) to `merge` are resolved to commit-IDs.  This means that the rules in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) are applied.  In general, `origin/name` resolves to one of the "remote branchs" that `git fetch` and `git push` keep up-to-date on every fetch-and-push.

A "remote branch", also called a "remote-tracking branch", is simply a branch-like label whose "full name" starts with `refs/remotes/`.  All the ones for the remote named `origin` are in `refs/remotes/origin/`.  In normal operation `git fetch` consults some remote (like `origin`) git repository and asks it: "hey, what branches do you have over there, and what are their SHA-1 values?"  When it gets the answers, it stores them locally, in *your* git repository: `refs/remotes/origin/master`, `refs/remotes/origin/devel`, and so on.  So that lets you know what things looked like "over there", the last time your git had a chance to sync up.

These should not be confused with what git calls "tracking branches" (or "local tracking branches").  Local branches are labels whose "full name" starts with `refs/heads/`.  They're considered "tracking" if they have "upstream" information associated with them.  You can have the upstream information put in when you first create the branch—this is typically the case for local branches with the "same" names as remote-branches, like `master` vs `origin/master`—or you can set (or change) it later with [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

*All* of these are different from the `git pull` syntax: `git pull origin master` is rather different, and much older, predating the whole idea of "remote-tracking branches" entirely.<sup>1</sup>  This sort of accidental resemblance, as it were, I think is the source of a whole lot of confusion (I know I found it confusing, years ago).

---

<sup>1</sup>Specifically, you used to (and still can) `git pull` from a URL rather than a "remote" name.  That went (and still goes) over to the other git repository as usual, and gets a list of at least some of its branches (sometimes just the one of interest).  But, because those are *its* branches, not yours, they are then recorded in a file called `FETCH_HEAD`.  So at this point, it will have brought `master` over from "over there", but put it into `FETCH_HEAD` rather than a remote-tracking branch—with a raw URL, you don't have a remote name, so there's no way to *name* the remote-tracking branch: there's no `origin` with which to construct the prefix `refs/remotes/origin`.  The `master` argument to `git-pull` then means: "go search through `FETCH_HEAD` to find their `master` branch."

Comment: Short answer could have been "see gitrevisions" but bonus points for explaining why git push and pull look different, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

When a branch is not specified, `git merge origin` will merge in whatever branch is set as default from the `origin` remote (generally `master`). In such cases, `git merge origin` and `git merge origin/master` will do the same thing. If you wanted to merge in a different branch from `origin`, though, you'd have to specify the branch.

Comment: More specifically, per [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), `origin` winds up matching `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, if that exists.  Where it doesn't (in a test repo here): `git merge origin` says `merge: origin - not something we can merge` but `git merge origin/master` merges (or in this case says `Already up-to-date.`).