# Does `origin/master` refer to a remote branch in a remote repository, or a remote-tracking branch in a local repository?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

*Version Control with Git* says

> By default, each new clone maintains a link back to its parent repository via a remote called origin. ... Git also configures the default origin remote with a default fetch refspec:
>
> ```
> fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```
>
> Establishing this refspec anticipates that you want to continue
>   updating your local repository by fetching changes from the
>   originating repository. In this case, the remote repository’s branches
>   are available in the clone on branch names prefixed with `origin/`,
>   such as `origin/master, origin/dev`, or `origin/maint`.

The above seems to say that `origin/master` refers to a remote branch in  a remote repository.

> if the alternate histories are in different repositories because of cloning, then the remote branch must be brought into your repository via a fetch operation. You can carry out the operation through a direct `git fetch` command or as part of a `git pull` command; it doesn’t matter which. In either case, the fetch brings the remote’s commits, here C and D, into your repository. In no way does the introduction of the alternate history with commits C and D change the history represented by X and Y; the two  alternate  histories  both  now exist simultaneously in your repository and form a more complex graph. Your history is represented by your master branch, and the remote history is represented by the `origin/master` remote-tracking branch.

[image]

The above seems to say that `origin/master` refers to a remote-tracking branch in  a local repository.

So does `origin/master` refer to a remote branch in  a remote repository, or a remote-tracking branch in  a local repository? When does it refer to which?

Comment: Here, *refers to* is the faulty (ambiguous, really) phrase. The actual value stored in `refs/remotes/origin/master` is stored locally. However, this value is *automatically updated* by a `git fetch` or `git push` that sees the value of `refs/heads/master` in the other Git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need the "master" in git merge origin/master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053597/why-do-i-need-the-master-in-git-merge-origin-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+between+master+origin%2Fmaster

Answer (score 4):

Your assessment of the first paragraph seems faulty to me : `origin/master` *does* refer to your local remote-tracking branch.

It's implied by the expression "the remote repository’s branches are available **in the clone** by branch names...". These are the local copies of the remote branches, updated only when you `fetch` but locally accessible at any point.